# Magento 2: Change Order Changes for Paypal Authorization on Magento Side

Tags: magento2, orders, custom, paypal, magento2.1.5

I'm able to achieve for some products it with be Authorization method instead of Sale for Paypal Express Checkout.

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\Api\Nvp.php** By overriding `getPaymentAction` method

It's Done on Paypal Side in SandBox it works fine.

Now it's not updating values on Magento Side. Still it's taking values from Config.

```
sales_order_payment
sales_payment_transaction
```

Above table has still value for Capture.

So for already Capture Order I need to Authorize in Magento. or How can we create order with Authorize Method for Paypal?

I have to get the order which is done Authorized & Apply Changes to it on Magento side.